# How to rename "object" in Facebook share_open_graph

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I try to create a share button to facebook using open graph API.

My function:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'og.likes',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        object: {
            'og:title': 'Custom Title',
            'og:url': 'https://site.url',
            'og:description': 'Customt Description',
            'og:image': 'Dynamic Image',
            'og:og:image:width': '2400',
            'og:image:height': '1260',
            'fb:app_id': 'APP_ID',    
            },
    })
```

If i use it like this, the post text is:

> John Doe likes an object von MyApp

How can i rename/remove the "object" in this post to a custom name or something like: `site, link` etc...

Another problem is, that the image of this post is always the small square picture and not the big one. I render the image on my server in 2400x1630.

Thank for your help!

Comment: You can’t. This is not a regular share to begin with, this is “abusing” og.likes functionality to be able to specify title, description etc. at run-time. And the image size might be due to that you specified the non-existent property `og:og:image:width`; but it might also be that this is just deliberately restricted to small square images, _because_ it is in Open Graph action, and not a regular share.

Comment: (_“You can’t.”_ - well, you could try to specify the type as well, together with the rest of those parameters - but I don’t know if that actually works, if it is _supposed_ to work … you’ll have to try. List of valid OG types can be found in the documentation.)

Comment: thanks! @misorude i tried to add a `og:type` as parameter, but that doesn't work. I can't find a customizable share functionallity, is there any one? The publish permission no longer works, i hopes these `share_open_graph` option is the beste way, i found some hints in the documentation. But it doesn't work for me like the examples.

Comment: _“I can't find a customizable share functionallity, is there any one?”_ - other than this - no; part of the fight against "fake news" (this was used too often to post articles with misleading title/description/thumbnail.)